# Is a function which is bounded along a path bounded?

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Does boundedness along a path of a multivariable function imply that the function is bounded?

Comment: the question as stated in the title uses the word *constant* that is later replaced by *bounded*. Which do you mean? Then, what do you mean by *boundedness along a path*: Along one particular path, or along every path? And isn't the answer easy, either way, did you try to answer this question yourself, what did you get? If the function is continuous then it is bounded along every path, as paths are compact.

Comment: I did get the answer in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, of course not: Think of the function $e^{x-y}$ which along the line $x=y$ is not only bounded, but even constant $1$ - yet it clearly is not bounded.